# I can't output elements within my array when I use a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, increment

I have made a function which adds rows to my html table dependent on the number of entries there are.

I am trying to make variable cdNoCell a unique ID with the id variable, which increments for each row that is made.

The problem I have is that the id prints out the total number of elements in my table in each row. So if I have 4 elements it prints out:

Actual Output:

```
ID    Title    Cost
4     a        10
4     b        12
4     c        6
4     d        10
```

Expected output:

```
ID    Title    Cost
1     a        10
2     b        12
3     c        6
4     d        10
```

My function code:

```
function showFunction(){
    var costArrayLength = costArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i<costArrayLength; i++){ //for loop adding elements to table
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); 
        var row = table.insertRow(-1); //adds each element to the bottom of table
        var cdNoCell = row.insertCell(0);
        var cdTitleCell = row.insertCell(1);
        var cdCostCell = row.insertCell(2); //inserts 3 cells 
        var id = 1;
        cdNoCell.innerHTML = id;
        cdCostCell.innerHTML = costArray[i];
        cdTitleCell.innerHTML = titleArray[i];
        id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put `var id = 1;` before your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change this line

`cdNoCell.innerHTML = id;`

with this

`cdNoCell.innerHTML = i + 1;`

Then you can remove both `var id = 1;` and `id++;` from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `var id = 1;` inside your loop the loop will restart and output 1 each time instead of increasing as expected.

I am kind of guessing on your arrays but below you can see a working snippet. Also keep in mind the insert functions are smart enough to know the *next* cell or row.

```js
titleArray = new Array("a","b", "c");
costArray = new Array(10, 20, 30);

function showFunction(){
    var costArrayLength = costArray.length;
    var id = 1;
    
    for (i = 0; i<costArrayLength; i++){ //for loop adding elements to table
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); 
        var row = table.insertRow(); //adds each element to the bottom of table
        var cdNoCell = row.insertCell();
        var cdTitleCell = row.insertCell();
        var cdCostCell = row.insertCell(); //inserts 3 cells 
        cdNoCell.innerHTML = id;
        cdCostCell.innerHTML = costArray[i];
        cdTitleCell.innerHTML = titleArray[i];
        id++;
    }
}

showFunction();
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border=1>

</table>
```